# Unable to open file in JAVA

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to open a file in JAVA using BufferedReader but it cannot open the file. Here is my code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


    try 
    {

       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));

       String line = null;
        while ((reader.readLine()!= null))  
        {
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }   
       reader.close();          
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file ");             
    }

}
```

It goes to the exception and prints Unable to open file.  Any suggestions why I cannot able to read it.

Comment: Have you thought of printing the exception message instead?

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`.  You won't know what type of `Exception` it is.  Catch the specific `IOException` instead.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Instead of your System.out.println, use "ex.printStackTrace()".  That will give you some basic detail.  If I had to guess, the fact that you have not specified the path to the file is the problem.  That would result in something like a "FileNotFoundException".

Comment: check for the file if it exists I suspect that you dont have file in your system

Comment: You are swallowing the exception, and its message and then asking the whole community to guess the problem? Java's Exceptions can be  a powerful mechanism to finding out what is going on, if it is used properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more nearly modern, try the Java 7 solution, taken from the `Paths` Javadoc:

```
final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.txt");  // working directory
try (final Reader r = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    String line = null;        
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}  // No need for catch; let IOExceptions bubble up.
   // No need for finally; try-with-resources auto-closes.
```

You'll need to declare `main` as throwing `IOException`, but that's okay. You have no coherent way of handling `IOException` anyway.  Just read the stack trace if an exception is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happened, but the problem seemed that I did not enter the complete path for the file even though the file was in the same folder. Ideally if the file is in the same folder then I wouldn't need to enter the entire pathname.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a check if it exists first:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.err.println(file.getName() + " not found. Full path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    /* Handling code, or */
    return;
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
/* other code... */
```

Comment: It's pointless. The exception message can tell you the same thing, or maybe a different thing, for example if you don't have read access. It is also vulnerable to a timing-window problem: the file's existence can change between the `exists()` test and constructing the `FileReader`. It's also redundant. Nothing to recommend it at all.

Comment: While the timing is true enough, I think that doing a check if it exists and then handling is a bit simpler.

One other thing to consider is that file.exists() returning false and Reader(File) throwing a FileNotFoundException do not mean the same thing. file.exists() will return true for directories and may return true for plain files, for which you don't have read privileges, while the Reader will throw a FileNotFoundException in these cases

Comment: Writing more code is never 'simpler'. The OS already checks existence while opening the file. Doing it again yourself is completely pointless. Your final sentence is another argument *against* calling `exists()`. For it to have any validity you would have to do all the checks that the operating system does, atomically, and that would still be redundant.

Comment: I suppose in reading files specifically, that would be an argument against myself. It is the way I learned, so I stand by my point.

For this specific case it was more an issue with absolute pathing, but overall I suppose that would be good in the way you stated.

Comment: I can't make head or tail of that, but what you suggest remains redundant, error-prone, and timing-window prone.